# How to display first tab by default using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i would like to show TAB1 by default Active when i load page every time

Script:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

}
```

i just need tab1 to show on load how can i do this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script

```
function init() {
    reset();

    document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")[0].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0].classList.add("active");
}

function reset() {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    reset();

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

}
```

And call init() in a script tag.

Comment: thank you, but now on load it is showing the content for all the tabs even though tab1 is active. how do i hide all the other content so that only tab1 content is showing ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the same rules you add on the click event but only to the first element of the arrays.  Something like this should work (assuming the element you want to display is the first one in the array):

```
<script>
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" into an array
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

    // display the first element of the array
    tabcontent[0].style.display = "block";

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" into an array
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

    // make first element active
    tablinks[0].classList.add("active");
</script>
```

And add the code at the end of your HTML page